# Source of clock_gettime

Tags: linux, time, linux-kernel

I've tried to understand the behavior of the function `clock_gettime` by looking at the source code of the linux kernel.
I'm currently using a `4.4.0-83-lowlatency` but I only could get the `4.4.76` source files (but it should be close enough).

My first issue is that there is several occurrence of the function. I chose `pc_clock_gettime` which appears to be the closest and the only one handling `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` but if I'm wrong, please correct me.

I tracked back the execution flow of the function and came to a mysterious `ravb_ptp_gettime64` and `ravb_ptp_time_read` which is related to the Ethernet driver.

So... If I understand correctly when I ask the system to give me the time, it ask to the Ethernet driver ?

This is the first time I looked into kernel code so I'm not used to it. If someone could give me an explanation of "how" and "why", it would be marvelous.

Comment: Read also [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) and study the code of your `libc`. It is likely that `clock_gettime` *don't* go into the kernel.

Comment: The goal was to understand the behavior of the function and to know if it use `rdtsc`.

Comment: It probably uses `rdtsc` thru the vdso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clock_gettime` use a mechanism named vDSO (*Virutal Dynamic Shared Object*). It's a shared library which is mapped in the user space by the kernel.

vDSO allow the use of `syscall` frequently without a drawback on performances. So the kernel "puts" time informations into memory which user programm can access. In the end, it won't be a system call but only a simple function call.